# Downloads kill WiFi

Tags: wireless, networking

Just installed 12.10 fresh. Using a run-of-the-mill Netgear N router, and a Netgear WN111v2 USB dongle.

THE PROBLEM: I attempt to install *anything* using update manager, software center, or via apt-get, and I can download a few megabytes no problem, and then POW. No internet connection. Connection to the router is fine, but the actual connectivity to the WAN is gone (download freezes, and no other software can access web either, including Chromium/FF). All other machines on the network continue working fine.

Now, if I disable networking and then reenable it, connectivity comes back. For a moment. I download a few more MB, and then it freezes again. And so on.

UPDATE: Now, if I attempt to load a website which has a lot of overhead (typekit, large images, etc.,), coming to a few MB, the WAN connection drops.

Importantly, I note that I used this dongle with only very occasional connectivity issues for more than year, with versions 11.04, 11.10, and 12.04. So something in 12.10 is (apparently) the culprit.

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for SYN attacks (if so you are dos'ing yourself ;) ) If so it could be a router setting.

Comment: I looked through the log file you referenced, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks like this is noted as bug #1066404. [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1066404)

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your system? If you haven't, you should.  It might be a bug with that version, so you should update it. If you don't know how, press CTRL+ALT+T and enter the following:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thats not really an answer, is it?

Comment: `apt-get update` doesn't actually update any packages.